# Perfino- How to monitor Oracle http server 11g

Tags: perfino

I have q requirement of monitoring the OHS server using the perfino. Could you please let me know how to configure this?..

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle HTTP Server is based on the Apache HTTP server. It is not written in Java and cannot be monitored by perfino.